# executable file must be placed in either the current working directory or somewhere in the command path

Tags: command-line, executable

I'm installing a command line program called plink that recommends this:

> The PLINK executable file should be placed in either the current
>   working directory or somewhere in the command path. This means that
>   typing "plink" or "./plink" at the command line prompt will run PLINK,
>   no matter which current directory you happen to be in. PLINK is a
>   command line program -- clicking on an icon with the mouse will get
>   you nowhere.

I have the PLINK executable file.  What should I do next?

Comment: Place it in either the current working directory or somewhere in the command path. What part of that isn't clear to you?

Comment: I guess I'm more confused about how I can type "plink" and not "./plink"; can't figure that out

Comment: Open a folder. On *nix (Linux), you have to type `./plink`. On Windows, it's `plink` (without the `./`).

Comment: What does "somewhere in the command path" mean?

Comment: Somewhere in a folder located on your system *PATH*. You really should find a tutorial for whatever operating system (Windows or Linux) you're using, particularly something related to script programming. These are basic OS use questions you're asking. (My previous comment was slightly unclear. Rather than saying *Open a folder*, I should have said *Open a terminal window or command prompt.* instead. My apologies - got sidetracked on a phone call before I caught it.)

Answer (score 0):

Run 'chmod +x plink' to grant the file execution rights.